# Is there some way I can do integrations on the complex plane without converting it to real and imaginary parts by hand?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

For example how do I actually write this in Mathematica?

```
         Integrate[ 1/(z^2+1/4), "z on the Unit Circle with origin as center" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `Integrate[f[z.{1, I}], z ∈ Circle[]]` you will get the **wrong** answer 8 Pi.
You need to parameterize your contour:

```
contour[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]}
f[z_] := 1/(z^2 + 1/4)

With[{z = contour[t].{1, I}},
 With[{d = D[z, t]}, Integrate[d*f[z], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
]

(* result: 0 *)
```

The sum of the residues at the two poles inside the circle is also zero:

```
(2 Pi I)(Residue[f[z], {z, I/2}] + Residue[f[z], {z, -I/2}]) == 0
```

Comment: Can we define a function call known as "ContourInt" so that this parametrisation is implemented automatically? This is good enough for now.

Comment: @QuasarSupernova No probably not reliably and in general. Although it's possible to get [`PlaneCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/PlaneCurve.html) data and the `"ParametricEquations"` property should you ever need to look up a specific curve's equations. This is easier to do numerically however if you want an approximate answer because we can discretize the curve region into a collection of lines which can be turned into a parametric form along the arc length.

Comment: This seems to work. ContourInt[f_, contour_] := 
 With[{z = contour[t].{1, I}}, 
  With[{d = D[z, t]}, Integrate[d*f[z], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example from the docs for `Integrate` (I added a radius `r`):

```
Integrate[f*Dt[z, t] /. z -> c + r * Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

It computes the integral of the expression `f` over the circle of radius `r` centered at `z == c`.  The expression `f` should be a formula for a function of the variable `z`.

Particular examples (the first is the OP's):

```
Integrate[1/(z^2 + 1/4)*Dt[z, t] /. z -> 0 + 1*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
(*  0  *)

Integrate[1/(z + 1/4)*Dt[z, t] /. z -> 0 + 1*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
(*  2 I \[Pi]  *)
```